# Drag SVG anchor line is circular method

Tags: svg

I am doing an experiment based on the code in the link below. But I don't know how.
`https://codepen.io/belfz/pen/BjPqOQ/right/`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>snap svg drag</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #main {
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <svg id="main"></svg>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js'></script>
  <script>
    var s = Snap("#main");
    var radius = 20;

    var linex1 = 60;
    var liney1 = 150;
    var linex2 = 500;
    var liney2 = 150;

    var circle1 = s.circle(linex1, liney1, radius);
    var circle2 = s.circle(linex2, liney2, radius);
    var line = s.line(linex1, liney1, linex2, liney2);
    line.attr({
      stroke: "#000",
      strokeWidth: 10,
      strokeLinecap: "round"
    });

    var move1 = function (dx, dy) {
      this.attr({
        // transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
        cx: linex1 + dx,
        cy: liney1 + dy
      });


      line.attr({
        x1: linex1 + dx,
        y1: liney1 + dy
      });

    };

    var move2 = function (dx, dy) {
      this.attr({
        // transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
        cx: linex2 + dx,
        cy: liney2 + dy
      });

      line.attr({
        x2: linex2 + dx,
        y2: liney2 + dy
      });

    };

    var start = function () {
      // this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
    };
    var stop = function () {
      linex1 = +line.attr('x1');
      liney1 = +line.attr('y1');
      linex2 = +line.attr('x2');
      liney2 = +line.attr('y2');
    };

    circle1.drag(move1, start, stop);
    circle2.drag(move2, start, stop);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In the code, dots are connected with straight lines, and the dots can be moved by dragging. I want to make the point-to-point line not a straight line, but a round circle curve. If anyone knows how, please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfCaK.png)

I want it to be a round red semicircle line like this.
When dragging a point, I want the angle of the curve to remain at the angle of the semicircle.